# How to create container with named volume?

Tags: java, docker-api

How to create container with named docker volume using the [docker-java library](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found solution:

```
Volume newVolume = new Volume("/target");

Bind bind = new Bind(namedVolumeName, newVolume);

CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd(imageId)
    .withName(containerName)
    .withHostConfig(HostConfig.newHostConfig().withBinds(bind))
    .exec();
```

Comment: Dude I love you. If I could give you more than one upvote I would! Thanks!!!